# How I can extract some numbers from a value in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to separate numbers from a value in bash. For example, I have a text file with the following row:

```
2015 0212 0455 25.0 L -20.270 -70.950 44.0  GUC        4.6LGUC                1
```

I need to separate the number `0212` in the second column in order to get two numbers: `num1=02` and `num2=12`. The same way for the number in the third column.

I'd like to find a generalized method with `awk` or `sed` to do this, because other files have this line:

```
2015 0212 0455 25.0 L -20.270 -70.950136.0  GUC        4.6LGUC                1
```

And in that case I also have to separate the value `-70.950136.0` in two numbers: `-70.950` and `136.0`. In this case the first number always has the same length: -70.950, -69.320, -68.000, etc.

Comment: Are those fixed-width columns, or how do you know where to split `-70.950136.0`?

Comment: In the case you mentioned, the first number that I'm trying to separate always has the same length: a negative two digit integer and 3 decimal digits. For example: -70.950, -69.240, -69.000

Comment: can we assume that fields are fixed length ?

Comment: The columns 2 and 3 in both cases have fixed lengths: a number of four digits. When the number in the column 8 is a number higher than 100, then happens what I show in the second example. In that case the length is always the same. But I have to separate that in two numbers as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming fixed lenght records

```
sed 's/.\{37\}/& /;s/.\{29\}/& /;s/.\{21\}/& /;s/.\{12\}/& /;s/.\{7\}/& /' YourFile
```

adapt on your need by adding or removing `s/.\{IndexOfCharInLine\}/& /;`